# Visual Studio Entity Data Wizard, Crashes when Trying to Connect to Oracle

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-6

I am running VS 2017,  ver 15.7.3  I have installed the Nuget Packages for Oracle,   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.

[image: Oracle Packages Installed on this Project]
I have my TNS file Configured to the proper Oracle Connection.  But When I open up the Entity Data Model Wizard, Select -> ADO.Net Entity Data Model Click ADD

[image: Adding New Entity Data Model]

Code First From Database  --> Click Next... . It just crashes out.  No Error... Nothing.  The Window just Closes
[image: Entity Data Model Code First Wizard Crash]

Some times it gets to the next screen and it lets me select the Oracle datasource and enter the proper credentials, but when I hit Next on that screen it just crashes out again.. I can never get past it?  Does anyone have a work around.  I'm sure I could create the Connection and the Entities Manually but there are just too many to for that approach to be practical.

Comment: Your `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework` seems out of date. Have you tried updating it?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the same problem by:

1. use Entity Framework Version 5.0 with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
   v18.3.0
2. delete your connection from web.Config
3. from Server Explorer window, remove all connections

Now, you can add your entity model through the ADO.Net Entity Data Model wizard.
In my case, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework wasn't needed.

Comment: but why it does not work with latest version of the packages?

Comment: The issue sound to  be from Oracle, as for providing a driver compatible to specific EF version.